# Hmm, something funny with the, what-do-they-call it, Gravatar

Tags: bug

I can be rather boring. Ever since I first signed up for this place I've had the same red <s>"flair"</s> gravatar pattern and never bothered to change it. As I type the familiar red one is up in the menu bar.[image: My old flair] But the one that was on a post I was just looking at was a different color, and a different pattern.[image: changed flair]

I'm used to the old one. I don't want it to change. heck, if I wanted to change it I'd probably come up with some custom image like all the cool kidz do; but I don't. Why did it change?

I also seem to have changed form reaching some large number of people (millions?) to ~447 (in the statistics page.) But for the moment I still seem to have 38.4K rep - I suppose that will vanish tomorrow...

Comment: The 447 people reached instead of 2.6 million is because you're looking at your profile here on meta not on the main site. See [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) if you want your rep to vanish. And the icon change has been happening recently; I'll go dig and see what I can find

Comment: Most likely: you usually use https, and today you're using http - is that likely? see answer for a lot more context

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - I certainly don't meta much.

Answer (score 8):

Gravatar be crazy; here's your 32-pixel image (`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG`):

[image: 32 pixel]

And here's your 64-pixel image (`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG`):

[image: 32 pixel]

---

Now, in case this is due to caching, here's what  I see for this:

[image]

If you look at the urls there, the only difference is the 32 vs 64; it *should* be defined entirely by the hash. So; blame gravatar! However, if you like one of them, I suggest you upload it as a custom image - then we'll use that instead. To do that, go to [your profile-edit page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/edit/18078) and click "Change picture":

[image]

The only place I can find the **red** image is on http 32-pixel; on https in either  32-pixel or 64-pixel, it is pink. So one other  possibility is that you *usually* use https, and today you've used http, hence the difference.

Here  they are on http:

(`http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG`):

[32 pixel http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)

And here's your 64-pixel image (`http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG`):

[32 pixel http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bb066028d98ac34985c7f060edac733?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG)

which for me looks like this:

[image]

This sounds like a problem in gravatar, but that is an external service that we can't touch.

Comment: Gravatar is crazy pants. I'm seeing different results than your screen shots (red for both sizes on HTTPS).

Comment: No change in my access. Guess I'll just change the darn thing, the new one annoys me.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I expect gravatar will fix the problem pretty quickly; some of my colleagues report that yours now work correctly for them (but some other ones are broken in similar ways)

Comment: @Marc this might be an issue with Varnish, I noticed from the headers that Gravatar are also using it. Judging from SE way to handle it, Gravatar only need to kick their cache hard enough.